# Possible to find block type?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

In Minecraft for Windows 10, is it possible to identify what type of block is currently behind the crosshair?

Comment: i know the f3 menu does that but im not sure if thats on that edition, gimme a sec, edit, its not, unfortunately there is no way to do that

Comment: right, no f3 available :(

Comment: afaik f3 is the only way without mods to see and afaik mods arent really all that available on bedrock. so i think this might be impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is impossible. However, you can press your Pick Block button (defaults to middle mouse button) while looking at a block to get the block you are currently looking at in item form. This may help you identify what block it is.

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thanks a lot!